# jQuery - Relative path to (ajax) load()

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$("#popMenu-fk").load("secure/student.php");
```

The calling files rests in folder "a" while the php script is in "a/Secure" folder. However, I am not being able to access that file from that path, but if I paste the file in same folder as calling file and use

```
$("#popMenu-fk").load("student.php");
```

it works!

Am I going wrong somewhere?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
$("#popMenu-fk").load("../a/secure/student.php");
```

That way no matter where you call this code from it knows where to go assuming that "/a" is right above the root and the code resides a single level above the root as well.

like if I have two folders...

```
<root>/js
<root>/ajax
```

and in the ajax folder I have a file caleld ajaxCalls.ashx

If i have a .js file in the js folder and I want to make ajax calls to the ajaxCalls.ashx file I would do something like

```
    url: "../ajax/ajaxCalls.ashx"
```

Comment: no problem... i ran into the same issue a while back trying to do virtually the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux then the file names are case sensitive and you have different casing in your sample, so maybe that is your problem?